# What is the difference between "the door opened" and "the door was opened"?

Tags: meaning

What is the difference between "the door opened" and "the door was opened"?  Are there subtle differences?

Comment: What did your previous research tell you? You have to tell us so that we do not recreate an entire academic text.

Comment: Yes, there are subtle differences, though they can both mean the same thing as well. _The door opened_ is the **inchoative** use of _open_; this means "came to be open; became open", and it's intransitive -- _open_ has no object, and nothing is said about why it opened. _The door was opened_ is a passive sentence, with the past participle of _open_ (not the past tense, as in _The door opened_) preceded by a form of _be_. This is the **causative** use of _open_, which means "cause to be open" -- with a passive, in this case, "was caused to be open", by some unknown agent. But deliberately.

Comment: @JohnLawler Why post as a comment and not an answer? That looks like a fine answer to me.

Answer (score 0):

active voice: the door opened 
passive voice: the door was opened

Comment: Welcome to ELU.SE. While this answer is technically correct, have a look at answers on the linked question to see the sort of thing which gets upvoted as useful.

Comment: Your answer is misleading, in that this doesn't give the normal active – passive transformation: active voice: _John opened the door_ <==> passive voice: _the door was opened_ [_by John_]. In both renderings here, the agent is the same (John). With the inchoative use, there may not even be an agent (and none can be mentioned).